# setting up mysql on Mac

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql5

I first installed Macports so it would be easier. Then installed mysql5,mysql5-server and py26-mysql.

Everything went ok. When I typed: `which mysql5` it returns `/opt/local/bin/mysql5

But when i try to enter the server: mysql5, an error is generated:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

How do I fix it?

I eventually wish to use mysql as a backend to a django project.
`

Comment: I think it would be better asked on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the server.  You should be able to run:

```
sudo /opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/mysql.server start
```

You can set it to run on boot with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
```

There is a [useful guide](http://2tbsp.com/content/install_and_configure_mysql_5_macports) with other details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `mysqld` (mysql daemon) is actually running on your Mac.

Remember: MySQL is a SQLServer, so it needs a daemon, probably listening on some TCP port to process client's requests.

To check if MySQL daemon is running, type into a terminal session:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
```

And mysql daemon process should be printed.

If it is not running, start it as stated by Mac Ports documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:
Find out where MySQL is actually using its sock by reviewing your my.cnf file and looking for

```
socket=<your mysql sock file>
```

Make sure this where your app, or whatever is using.
You are going to run into this problem when you hook up to Django. MySQLdb expects /tmp/mysql.sock. You need to override this in your settings.py file by setting:

```
SOCK: '<your actual sock file'>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a quick and easy tutorial at https://kidcodely.wordpress.com/2017/10/07/database-setup/

This will take you through the full installation on a mac where you'll learn how to create databases from Terminal.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)